# CloudWatch Alarm triggers more often than expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a problem with one of my CloudWatch alarms and i cant quite figure out.

I have a metric for one of my LogGroups, that inserts 1 data point, whenever a "Fatal Alarm" is logged within the application.

A fatal alarm was logged this night at 01:44:51. My alarm changed to ALARM state at 01:45 (as expected), but also went into ALARM state at 02:35 and 03:05

I have a bunch of screen dumps with all the information that i believe is necessary for pointing me in the right direction:

**Only one Fatal Log:**
[image]

.

**We can also see theres only one fatal log, if we graph the metric:**
[image]

.

**Alarm state changes:**
[image]

.

**Alarm state changed to ALARM 1 (the expected one):**
[image]

.

**Alarm state changed to ALARM 2 (not expected):**
[image]

.

**Alarm state changed to ALARM 3 (not expected):**
[image]

.

**Alarm configuration:**
[image]

Am i doing some kind of obvious misconfiguration? I'm a bit confused as to what i am doing wrong

Thanks in advance!

Frederik

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your configuration as far as I can see. But if you want to see a graph corresponding to your incidents, you should change the period to fifteen minutes or an hour. Note that your alarm period is set to `30 minutes`.

Comment: Do you mean the "Alarm Preview" in the last picture? I cropped that out of the screenshot :) Do you believe that the 30 minute period could have anything to do with the "multiple triggering of alarm state" ?

Comment: No, I am referring to the first picture. Go to the CloudWatch console and change the period to 1 hour. Do you still see the same graph?